# What to do with posts with images that are not hosted on SO's imgur?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

The organisation I work in has a rather strict filter set up on internet traffic; it's so bad, for instance, that at one point we couldn't access Trello. Putting requests in to our network team to allow the resource, would either be approved or rejected, and usually takes about a month to process.

Because of its association with Stack Exchange, networks (on our request) have unblocked the SO's imgur site ... grudgingly ... a while ago, but our filter is so strict that even standard imgur is blocked to us!

This problem also spans to many of the sites that people use to post some images in their questions and answers, for instance, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access/3296393#3296393) has images on *lifefilestore.com*.

What should I do in these cases?

1. Flag the post for moderator intervention
2. Update the question/answer with a possible alternative (based on a respectable assumption from the text)
3. Suck it up and leave the post as it was
4. Ask the OP, though they may no longer use the site

In the case above, I used the first option.  *(Note: sorry moderators!)*

Comment: I've been in your shoes before, and this is not really an answer to your question, but more as a workaround: if your company allow uploading image to Stack's Imgur, then you can copy the (URL of the) image and try to reupload it with Stack's own image uploader. At least I could see the image with this approach.

Comment: @AndrewT. - I think I see what you're getting at; kind of tricking the Stack image loader to pull based on the URL.  Good idea.

Comment: Don't forget the companies that block imgur so it could be a situation where the image is hosted in a place they can use because imgur is blocked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Flag the post for moderator intervention

No. This is not an exception that requires moderator intervention. **Do not use flags for this kind of situation**. If you did, it's no big deal. They'll decline your flag and carry on. Moderators really love flags anyway, even if only to decline them.

> Update the question/answer with a possible alternative (based on a respectable assumption from the text)

Only if you are really, really sure of what the image contains. But most likely, **no**. If you can't see the original image, you can end up messing it up for everyone else.

> Suck it up and leave the post as it was

Always an option. You can come back to the post from different location and/or at a different time, and edit it there.

> Ask the OP, though they may no longer use the site

This is helpful, and the *raison d'etre* for comments. You are asking for clarification and suggesting improvements. Maybe the post author will take heed, or any one else that sees the post (e.g. I did it for the answer you linked).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I see you edited the answer, but put them into imgur itself, not into the SE imgur site!  (Sorry - I'll edit my question to make this more obvious)

Comment: It was faster doing it this way, sorry. I didn't realize it would have been blocked for you as well. Going through SO UI is slower than just pasting the images on imgur and replacing the URLs on the questions... I'll do it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: No problem.  It's not your fault - our filter is sooo strict.

Comment: Fixed it for you. Hope it was worth it.

Comment: Sorry - I would have been quite happy to attempt the edit myself, and had a good suspicion of what should be there.  However, images are very contextual to what I was (and wasn't seeing).  Really, this question wasn't simply about the one instance - it's more about the process of what I should do on any other occasion that I encounter this problem with blocked/filtered content.  Thank-you very much for your help Yivi.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I do think that a question/answer that can only be consumed by use of the images isn't always helpful anyway; especially for those like yourself that can't access said image. In my opinion an image should *compliment* the question/answer, but it should not solely be the answer/question. Image only answers are a little like link only answers in my opinion; if the link to the image becomes dead (and that includes to SO/SE's imgur site) then the answer/question is useless to everyone without a complimentary description.

To put a little perspective on this, let's say someone posts a question along the lines of  this:

> How do keep carriage returns and line breaks in my data, when I copy of SQL Server Management Studio?

You could find someone respond with an answer like the below:

> You can turn this on in the options here:
>
> [image]

Although the above *answers* the question, for those that can't access the image, or if the image is no longer available, the answer is actually useless and does **not** solve the question.

If, however, the answer described those steps as well, it's far more useful:

> You can turn this feature on in the Options menu. `Tools` -> `Options`. Then open the  `Query Results` -> `SQL Server` -> `Results to Grid` pane, and tick the `Retain CR/LF on copy or save` check box, like below:
>
> [image]

If an answer does only contain an image solution, and you feel it should add a description to the steps then i would suggest asking for those steps in a comment on the answer. If, however, the answer isn't consumable without the image, you could see it as unhelpful or not useful and downvote it. Then you could also ask a new question, citing the answer you found and explaining why it doesn't help (meaning you don't have it closed as a duplicate). Hopefully then, another volunteer would give you an answer that is more verbose and helpful to both yourself and others, and includes a non-image only solution.

Comment: I completely agree, and have pointed this out before to users (sorry - can't provide any examples for this without trawling my comments); it *is* the same as a link only answer. As I said, as well, nudging the user with a comment is a moot point if they no longer use the site.

Comment: Why I added the point about downvoting and asking a new question, citing the question you saw and saying why it isn't helpful @Paul. A lot of questions get closed as duplicates because the OP can't show *why* it's not a duplicate, or explain why. Saying that the answer doesn't help due to a broken link image is more than enough reason for it to not be a duplicate.

Comment: To be fair, the example that I gave, and discussed with Yivi above, did have some relevant detail, but it still required more; so close but no cigar. In this case, the images were the final part of the jigsaw and, while I had a fair idea what was going on, I was still off target when Yivi did update the images. ('The devil's in the detail', as they say.)

Comment: (Referring to my last comment) - I certainly didn't see that post as a duplicate.